# Combine 4 transparent PNG images on top of each other in an ASP.NET environment

Tags: asp.net, html, png

I came across the solution I need in PHP but I need one that I can use that's just as simple in an ASP.NET environment.

I am combining 4 transparent png images to create a single image (Lets say its a custom certificate) with one of 4 background images, one of 4 header logos, one of 18 category titles and another variable image that stack just like they would in Photoshop.  Instead of doing up over 1000 images I want the page to generate this image based on input variables.

I am at the point now where everything stacks nicely but I can't for the life of me find a way to merge these images together for the visitor to save locally as a single image.

I found the perfect PHP solution here:

[Combine 2-3 transparent PNG images on top of each other with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397377/combine-2-3-transparent-png-images-on-top-of-each-other-with-php)

What can I do that accomplishes the same thing?

Comment: Show us the code, so we know what you have done and suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

.NET has lots of image processing capabilities.  Look at the `Image` class.  It lets you load and save images.  You can use the `Graphics.FromImage()` to return a graphics object that will let you draw another graphic onto an existing image.  These steps should get you there once you've discovered the details enabling the transparency.