# How to dynamically merge two photos into a new image

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api, image-processing

I'm grabbing photos from FB's API and I'd like to merge a transparent filter on top and then save it as a new image to then post is a new picture to FB. I've looked into using Canvas however toDataURL() only works when the photos are on the same server. I've also tried using the filter as the src for an image and setting the fb pic as the background image but you can't save it off as this as it's editing through CSS. Any suggestion on how to actually blend the photos together and actually be able to save as a new image?

Comment: What backend are you using? If PHP, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397377/combine-2-3-transparent-png-images-on-top-of-each-other-with-php

Comment: Hi, if you are using PHP i would use ImageMagick (http://imagemagick.org/script/index.php) and IMagick (download: http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick, documentation: http://php.net/imagick). If you use this solution let me know and I'll write up as an answer.