# Combine 3 jpg images on top of each other with PHP

Tags: php, image, upload, jpeg

This question already asked but that not solve my issue.

I want to `combine` 3 `JPG` images top of each other using with `PHP`.

I tried this in `PNG` that's working fine. But when i using `JPG` image i got black screen like this

[image]

**This is my code:**

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

function get_file($file, $from) {
    if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . "/" . $file)) { file_put_contents(__DIR__ . "/" . $file, file_get_contents($from)); }
}
get_file("background-layer-111.jpg", "https://img.youtube.com/vi/CQElIZzzlpc/hqdefault.jpg");
get_file("icon-layer-222.jpg", "https://img.youtube.com/vi/OK_JCtrrv-c&t=1732s/hqdefault.jpg");
get_file("stars-layer-333.jpg", "https://img.youtube.com/vi/1vYMqjNafww/hqdefault.jpg");

$bgFile = __DIR__ . "/background-layer-111.jpg"; 
$imageFile = __DIR__ . "/icon-layer-222.jpg"; 
$watermarkFile = __DIR__ . "/stars-layer-333.jpg"; 


$x = $y = 76;


$final_img = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y);


$image_1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($bgFile);
$image_2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageFile);
$image_3 = imagecreatefromjpeg($watermarkFile);


imagealphablending($final_img, true);
imagesavealpha($final_img, true);


imagecopy($final_img, $image_1, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x, $y);
imagecopy($final_img, $image_2, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x, $y);
imagecopy($final_img, $image_3, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x, $y);

ob_start();
imagejpeg($final_img);
$watermarkedImg = ob_get_contents(); 
ob_end_clean(); 

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $watermarkedImg;
```

> Note: My code working for only `PNG`, i want to work with all image format like `JPG`. I refer this url  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397377/combine-2-3-transparent-png-images-on-top-of-each-other-with-php)

Comment: Unlike PNG, JPG does not have alpha channel: nothing in JPG is transparent. You might be able to use `imagecolortransparent` to convert your JPGs into something blendable.

Comment: i can change jpeg function using this code. It can be working.